# Script task runs fine when we put break points in the script, but goes into infinite loop when break points are removed

Tags: ssis

I am using visual studio 2017, In that I am using script task to copy the file from Source folder to destination folder and then delete the file from source folder, now the problem is when I put break points script task is running fine and does not throw an exception, when the break points are removed, It goes to infinite look.

```
        public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        String filename = Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value.ToString();
        String filefullpath = Dts.Variables["$Project::ThreatConnectSourcePath"].Value.ToString()+ filename;
        String archpath = Dts.Variables["$Project::ThreatConnectArchievePath"].Value.ToString() + filename;




        File.Delete(filefullpath);


        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
```

Comment: Please provide the Script code

Comment: It is a simple script task where I am trying to delete the files from source solder after its being loaded, I have tried using if condition to check if file exist then delete.